# Arrange blocks of code in an MVC 3 view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a complex View (cshtml) in my MVC3 project. Depending on different variables, the parts of this code must be shown in a different order. How can I separate blocks of Razor/HTML code and "include" them at the proper position? 
Looking for something like that:

```
@{ CODEBLOCK 1
...
}

@{ CODEBLOCK 2
...
}

@if (bla==1) {
    include CODEBLOCK 1
    include CODEBLOCK 2
} else {
    include CODEBLOCK 2
    include CODEBLOCK 1
}
```

I don't want to use HtmlPartial, since I don't want to pass all vars, the model and other stuff to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use helper methods:

```
@helper CodeBlock1()
{
    ...
}

@helper CodeBlock2()
{
    ...
}

@if (bla==1) {
    CodeBlock1();
    CodeBlock2();
} else {
    CodeBlock2();
    CodeBlock1();
}
```

As a bonus, it's type safe and allows arguments.

Comment: That's it :-)
A little change in detail: I use
    @CodeBlock1();to get the output as it is typed in the helper and as it was before I inserted the helper

Answer (score 1):

What about layout sections?

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx

```
@section CODEBLOCK1 {
...
}

@section CODEBLOCK2 {
...
}

@if (bla==1) {
    @RenderSection("CODEBLOCK1");
    @RenderSection("CODEBLOCK2");
} else {
    @RenderSection("CODEBLOCK2");
    @RenderSection("CODEBLOCK1");
}
```

Comment: Had this idea, but @RenderSection doesn't work with a directly called .cshtml file.

Comment: What do you mean directly called?

Comment: The view is used in other views via:
@Html.Action("DatePicker", "Date", myRouteValues)

And using @RenderSection I get the error:
The file "~/Views/Date/DatePicker.cshtml" cannot be requested directly because it calls the "RenderSection" method.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried out [Razor Sections](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

While I like Morten Christiansen's approach, another approach that I'll just throw out as a way to "move stuff around" on the page would be to use jQuery to adjust where things are.

Assuming a view with something like this:

```
<div id = "div1">
   Something
</div>
<div id = "div2>
   Something Else
</div>
```

and then some jQuery to determine whether to do the swap:

```
if (someCondition)
{
   $('#div2').insertBefore('#div1');
}
```

Again, I just throw that out there as one other possible way to adjust which comes first, but I certainly like Morten's idea better.